# Iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, distributed-training

I am trying to adapt this [COLA repo](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/cola) to my audio dataset which I have in a local folder. I mainly change file contrastive.py to adapt method _get_ssl_task_data() to my new database.

However, I get an error triggered from model.fit (which calls my model.train_step(data) method below). I tried to fix this error by modifying data shape inside train_step but without any success.

I am not sure if this is an error because of shape or data type incompatibility or because I need to add more things to adapt my graph. Does anyone please know what's wrong with my code ? how can I replace the use of tf.Tensor in my case if this is really the issue ?

Here's the content of contrastive.py:

```
"""Self-supervised model for contrastive learning task."""

import os

import tensorflow as tf

import constants
import data
import network

import numpy as np
import librosa
import sys, os, glob


class ContrastiveModel:
  """Provides functionality for self-supervised constrastive learning model."""

  def __init__(self,
               strategy,
               ssl_dataset_name,
               ds_dataset_name,
               model_path,
               experiment_id,
               batch_size,
               epochs, learning_rate,
               embedding_dim,
               temperature,
               similarity_type,
               pooling_type,
               noise,
               steps_per_epoch = 1000):
    """Initializes a contrastive model object."""

    self._strategy = strategy
    self._ssl_dataset_name = ssl_dataset_name
    self._ds_dataset_name = ds_dataset_name
    self._model_path = model_path
    self._experiment_id = experiment_id

    self._batch_size = batch_size
    self._epochs = epochs
    self._learning_rate = learning_rate
    self._temperature = temperature
    self._embedding_dim = embedding_dim
    self._similarity_type = similarity_type
    self._pooling_type = pooling_type
    self._noise = noise

    self._steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch
    self._shuffle_buffer = 1000
    self._n_frames = None
    self._n_bands = 64
    self._n_channels = 1
    self._input_shape = (-1, self._n_frames, self._n_bands, self._n_channels)

  def _prepare_example(self, example):
    #Creates an example (anchor-positive) for instance discrimination.
    example = tf.cast(example, tf.float32) / float(tf.int16.max)
    x = tf.math.l2_normalize(example, epsilon=1e-9)

    waveform_a = data.extract_window(x)
    mels_a = data.extract_log_mel_spectrogram(waveform_a)
    frames_anchors = mels_a[Ellipsis, tf.newaxis]

    waveform_p = data.extract_window(x)
    waveform_p = waveform_p + (
        self._noise * tf.random.normal(tf.shape(waveform_p)))
    mels_p = data.extract_log_mel_spectrogram(waveform_p)
    frames_positives = mels_p[Ellipsis, tf.newaxis]

    return frames_anchors, frames_positives

  #my own added method to create dataset
  def file_load(self, wav_name, mono=False):
    try:
        return librosa.load(wav_name, sr=None, mono=mono)
    except:
        logger.error("file_broken or not exists!! : {}".format(wav_name))

  #my own added method to create dataset
  def make_data(self, folder_name):
    all_name = glob.glob(folder_name)
    files = []
    for name in all_name:
        files.append(self.file_load(name)[0])
    #return tf.map_fn(lambda file: _prepare_example(file), np.array(files))
    files = np.array(files, dtype=object)
    r = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, 0, dynamic_size=True)
    for file in files:
        r = r.write(r.size(), self._prepare_example(file))
        #r = r.write(r.size(), file)
    return r.stack()

  #my adapted method to create dataset
  def _get_ssl_task_data(self):
    #Prepares a dataset for contrastive self-supervised task.
    data_dir='path/to/my/audio/folder'
    dataset = self.make_data(data_dir + "/*")
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dataset)
    ds = dataset.repeat()
    ds = ds.shuffle(self._shuffle_buffer, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
    #ds = ds.map(self._prepare_example, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    ds = ds.batch(self._batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
    ds = ds.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    return ds

  def train(self):
    """Trains a self-supervised model for contrastive learning."""

    train_dataset = self._get_ssl_task_data()
    train_dataset = self._strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(train_dataset)

    with self._strategy.scope():
      contrastive_network = network.get_contrastive_network(
          embedding_dim=self._embedding_dim,
          temperature=self._temperature,
          pooling_type=self._pooling_type,
          similarity_type=self._similarity_type)
      contrastive_network.compile(
          optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(self._learning_rate),
          loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])

    ssl_model_dir = f"{self._ssl_dataset_name.value}/{self._experiment_id}/"
    ckpt_path = os.path.join(self._model_path, ssl_model_dir, "ckpt_{epoch}")
    model_checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath=ckpt_path, save_weights_only=True, monitor="loss")

    backup_path = os.path.join(self._model_path, ssl_model_dir, "backup")
    backandrestore_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.experimental.BackupAndRestore(
        backup_dir=backup_path)

    log_dir = os.path.join(self._model_path, "log", self._experiment_id)
    tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir)

    contrastive_network.fit(
        train_dataset,
        epochs=self._epochs,
        batch_size=self._batch_size,#added
        steps_per_epoch=self._steps_per_epoch,
        verbose=2,
        callbacks=[
            model_checkpoint_callback,
            backandrestore_callback,
            tensorboard_callback,
        ])
```

And here's the code of the ContrastiveModel:

```
class ContrastiveModel(tf.keras.Model):
  """Wrapper class for custom contrastive model."""

  def __init__(self, embedding_model, temperature, similarity_layer,
               similarity_type):
    super().__init__()
    self.embedding_model = embedding_model
    self._temperature = temperature
    self._similarity_layer = similarity_layer
    self._similarity_type = similarity_type

  def train_step(self, data):
    #tried to modify data shape but in vain
    # shape of received data from input is [batch_size, 2, 98, 64, 1]
    #data = tf.transpose(data, [1, 0, 2, 3, 4]) #failed attempt, with same error
    anchors, positives = data # This one alone doesn't work either

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      inputs = tf.concat([anchors, positives], axis=0)
      embeddings = self.embedding_model(inputs, training=True)
      anchor_embeddings, positive_embeddings = tf.split(embeddings, 2, axis=0)

      # logits
      similarities = self._similarity_layer(anchor_embeddings,
                                            positive_embeddings)

      if self._similarity_type == constants.SimilarityMeasure.DOT:
        similarities /= self._temperature
      sparse_labels = tf.range(tf.shape(anchors)[0])

      loss = self.compiled_loss(sparse_labels, similarities)
      loss += sum(self.losses)

    trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
    self.compiled_metrics.update_state(sparse_labels, similarities)
    return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}


def get_efficient_net_encoder(input_shape, pooling):
  """Wrapper function for efficient net B0."""
  efficient_net = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(
      include_top=False, weights=None, input_shape=input_shape, pooling=pooling)
  # To set the name `encoder` as it is used by supervised module for
  # to trainable value.
  return tf.keras.Model(efficient_net.inputs, efficient_net.outputs, name="encoder")


def get_contrastive_network(embedding_dim,
                            temperature,
                            pooling_type="max",
                            similarity_type=constants.SimilarityMeasure.DOT,
                            input_shape=(None, 64, 1)):
  """Creates a model for contrastive learning task."""
  inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape)
  encoder = get_efficient_net_encoder(input_shape, pooling_type)
  x = encoder(inputs)
  outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(embedding_dim, activation="linear")(x)
  if similarity_type == constants.SimilarityMeasure.BILINEAR:
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()(outputs)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Activation("tanh")(outputs)
  embedding_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
  if similarity_type == constants.SimilarityMeasure.BILINEAR:
    embedding_dim = embedding_model.output.shape[-1]
    similarity_layer = BilinearProduct(embedding_dim)
  else:
    similarity_layer = DotProduct()
  return ContrastiveModel(embedding_model, temperature, similarity_layer,
                          similarity_type)
```

When I run the code, which is distributed with strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy() in above code, I get this full error:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 297, in stop_on_exception
    yield
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_run.py", line 323, in run
    self.main_result = self.main_fn(*self.main_args, **self.main_kwargs)
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 667, in wrapper
    return converted_call(f, args, kwargs, options=options)
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 396, in converted_call
    return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options)
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 478, in _call_unconverted
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 820, in run_step
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
  File "/lfs/eq/tim/project_sept2020/cola/network.py", line 66, in train_step
    anchors, positives = data
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 505, in __iter__
    self._disallow_iteration()
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 498, in _disallow_iteration
    self._disallow_when_autograph_enabled("iterating over `tf.Tensor`")
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 474, in _disallow_when_autograph_enabled
    raise errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError(
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
I1129 04:56:14.756884 140640742516480 coordinator.py:217] Error reported to Coordinator: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 297, in stop_on_exception
    yield
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_run.py", line 323, in run
    self.main_result = self.main_fn(*self.main_args, **self.main_kwargs)
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 667, in wrapper
    return converted_call(f, args, kwargs, options=options)
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 396, in converted_call
    return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options)
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 478, in _call_unconverted
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 820, in run_step
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
  File "/lfs/eq/tim/project_sept2020/cola/network.py", line 66, in train_step
    anchors, positives = data
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 505, in __iter__
    self._disallow_iteration()
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 498, in _disallow_iteration
    self._disallow_when_autograph_enabled("iterating over `tf.Tensor`")
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 474, in _disallow_when_autograph_enabled
    raise errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError(
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/lfs/eq/tim/project_sept2020/cola/main.py", line 154, in <module>
    app.run(main)
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/lfs/eq/tim/project_sept2020/cola/main.py", line 108, in main
    model.train()
  File "/lfs/eq/tim/project_sept2020/cola/contrastive.py", line 194, in train
    contrastive_network.fit(
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1132, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 784, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 827, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 681, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2998, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3390, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3225, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 998, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 590, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 985, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: in user code:

    /misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:837 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:827 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2731 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_strategy.py:628 _call_for_each_replica
        return mirrored_run.call_for_each_replica(
    /misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_run.py:93 call_for_each_replica
        return _call_for_each_replica(strategy, fn, args, kwargs)
    /misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_run.py:234 _call_for_each_replica
        coord.join(threads)
    /misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py:389 join
        six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
    /misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/six.py:703 reraise
        raise value
    /misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py:297 stop_on_exception
        yield
    /misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_run.py:323 run
        self.main_result = self.main_fn(*self.main_args, **self.main_kwargs)
    /misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:820 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /lfs/eq/tim/project_sept2020/cola/network.py:66 train_step
        anchors, positives = data
    /misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:505 __iter__
        self._disallow_iteration()
    /misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:498 _disallow_iteration
        self._disallow_when_autograph_enabled("iterating over `tf.Tensor`")
    /misc/home/rc/tim/anaconda3/envs/tfenv2cola/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:474 _disallow_when_autograph_enabled
        raise errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError(

    OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.

Epoch 1/100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prolem was simply because my preprocessing was returning an array instead of a tuple that is required in the graph. So, the solution was to use tensorflow dataset utils to create my entire pipeline from files. This is also more efficient and uses much less memory of course.

```
def load_dataset(folder):

  # Get the files
  filenames = glob.glob(folder)
  files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)

  # Load waveforms
  dataset = files_ds.map(
  lambda x: tf.numpy_function(
    func=lambda y: np.array(file_load(y.decode("utf-8"))[0]),
    inp=[x],
    Tout=tf.float32,
  )
  )
  return dataset
```